# How can I recover from SharePoint configuration errors after promoting the server to a Domain Controller?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 VM setup in VirtualBox and I was using local machine accounts to handle security on the server.

While preparing for a demo it came time to have some meaningful users on my VM image.  I followed some docs on promoting my server to a Domain Controller in a new forrest.

So now I have [MachineName].SPDEMO.CONTOSO.com and I can add users as needed.

However, when I try to connect to my SharePoint sites I am getting a white screen with the error:

```
"Cannot connect to the configuration database"
```

I changed the pool identity account of each of my IIS app pools to the new Administrator account and started the services successfully but I can't get the SQL services to start up.

When I try to start them I get the following error:

```
Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log.  If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 17058.
```

In the event log I see the following error:

```
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with service-specific error %%17058.
```

Can I recover from this or should I roll back or just uninstall the Domain Controller role.  I'd like to keep the server as a standalone DC so I can do some user profile creation/management but I need the SharePoint bits to work as well.

Comment: Have you changed the SQL Service account too?

Comment: I think Toni's point is good, but to be honest I simply wouldn't mix the sharepoint and DC roles and expect a good working system afterwards. Can you not create a second small VM to host the DC role?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did update the SQL service account as well.  The separate VM as a DC option is good but then I have to figure out all the magic to get networking between my VM instances but not outside my host where my company domain can pick them up and get confused.  I was trying to avoid that extra work but if that is the best option I could head down that path.

Comment: Toni, I spoke too soon.  I didn't change the sql service account because it was set up as a network service.  After double checking I configured it as a user account and that cleared up the issue.  Can you add that as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: will add as answer. If you have HW resources add another VM for DC and SQL too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a problem with SQL Service account, have you changed it?